# Is there anything that can be done about losing the cursor in combat?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The mouse cursor in Guild Wars 2 seems easy-to-lose in combat situations, making it difficult to know where to target ground-targeted skills quickly. This poor coordination can lead to situations where my reaction time is significantly faster than my ability to react, leaving me with missed opportunities, particularly in large-scale WvW combat.

- The default color of the mouse cursor is a yellow-brown tint, which can blend into terrain backgrounds.
- The mouse cursor has fairly subtle tint changes based on what is hovered over (green for allies, red for enemies).
- Whenever one of the mouse buttons is held down, the mouse cursor is invisible, which can make it easy to lose track of where the mouse cursor was prior to rotating your camera or character.

Is there any way to make the cursor more visible or easier to keep track of?

Comment: There are probably some mods for this.

Comment: @DavidYell Tampering with the game files can result in a ban in a MMORPG. So I would not advise to do that.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Each to their own.

Comment: @DavidYell: I wouldn't be so flippant about it; tampering via mods is a serious violation of terms you agreed to when you installed the game. Having said that, see [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/10a0qk/official_response_clarifying_the_stance_on_mods/) in which Gaile from ArenaNet clarifies "the distinction between advantage-giving programs and those that simply make it easier to play the game under specific circumstances". I _believe_ (but of course can't be sure) that "Combat Mode" (google it with "guild wars 2") falls into the latter category.

Comment: I am not for or against them, my comment was merely stating that you would probably achieve this using a mod. Please do not vilify me for it. I don't use any mods, so please, extinguish torches and down pitchforks. We are drifting off topic.

Comment: @DavidYell: No pitchforks in sight, relax. ;-) Don't worry, I wasn't trying to say you were doing anything illegal, just that I wouldn't answer the question, "Where can I get food in New York City?" with, "There are probably some convenience stores where they won't notice some items missing." Extreme example, I know, but it's a slippery slope. And, imho, probably not really off-topic for a question that _seems_ to be asking about mods (probably not intended). It's a grey zone; I won't volunteer an answer, just recommend that you make sure whatever you do doesn't violate any rules. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a mod that makes your cursor size bigger. It is called Yolo Mouse. Here is a link to it: http://pandateemo.github.io/YoloMouse/

Comment: That is a fantastic tool and does exactly what I need from it! Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: @Koviko: No problem, i'm always happy to help. If you need any more help just contact me.

Answer (score -2):

Another solution can be found here:

This program can make it impossible to lose the cursor, and sometimes you will wish you could lose the cursor :).

Comment: Some MMORPG's actually will forbid applications such as the CursorNode dude to its inherit ability to obtain an unfair advantage. Also, providing just a video without the actual product does not immediately assist OP in finding an answer. I would suggest adding a link to the product specifically.

Comment: A link to the program is in the video description I think. The only game I came across that didn't work with cursor node initially was lineage 2. Even so, after a little fiddling, it worked. They can sure forbid people using a large cursor, but they have no way to stop people using one. Google found cursornode at [link](http://cursornode.com).